# Unity vs Udk vs CryEngine

Tags: unity-game-engine

Which is the best to learn? What are there advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Unity3d is now, probably, let's say ... 500 times? more popularly used than the other two.  if you want to work, learn Unity first.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, UDK is the easiest to learn with its fantastic UnrealScript where pretty much any environment variable can be controlled. It also is the most powerful with complemented tools with superb Autodesk 3ds Max / Maya integration. UDK is free by the way.

Unity is based on Mono which provides C# as the scripting language. If you know C# and want to have the absolute power of Visual Studio, Unity will fit the bill. On the other hand, Unity is not free.

CryEngine is the most fascinating of all in terms of graphics and it is bundled with a superb environment editor. On the other hand it is the most expensive of all. Plus it may not be extendable as UDK or Unity, especially if you want to use it in visualization.

Comment: UDK is free to play around with but for a commercial project you need to buy a license or a mix of a license+royality.

With Unity3D on the other hand you do have a free version and paid (Pro) version. Now free version of Unity3D is not restricted on how you can use - so you can use it for commercial projects. The Pro version is also quite cheap (compared to UDK license).

CryEngine is quite extendable, given you have the right license (again). But it is as you mentioned quite over the top in price.

Comment: and just as an update of the current situation, Unity "Personal Ed" is free if you (or your game dev company) make less than $100K per year. Unity Pro currently costs about $75/month as a service (they will stop providing updates to non-service licenses on March 3, 2017, as they want everyone on that service I guess). On another hand UDK is completely free until you start making $3000 (or more) per quarter revenue from your game, at which point the software costs 5% of that revenue. CryEngine on another hand is offered on "pay as much as you want" basis.

Comment: My personal opinion as someone just fresh into looking at a 3d engine is that crytek is the current best option but the other two are great as well with minor issues here and there.